# Talend : capture value from row1 and replace it in the entire column

Tags: java, talend

I want to take uk from 1st row and replace it in the entire country column without changing the values in zones. I have tried regex expression from expression builder but failed.

| COUNTRY | ZONE |
| --- | --- |
| UK | 12 |
| AU | 44 |
| FR | 21 |
| GER | 20 |
| FR | 02 |

Comment: You don't need regex to just replace UK in the expression builder in your tMap. Try `row1.COUNTRY.equals("UK") ? "" : row1.COUNTRY`

Comment: If you are wanting to just put a static variable just drop a tmap and in column country type "UK" as static .

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa can u provide any good solutions.

Comment: @Adrian Thank you for the reply. Actually i have exported a file in which the first row is a two digit capslock code and the rest are either int or string. I want to populate the entire column with 'first row value'. I want to generalize this so that it will automatically detect the first row and replace the rest with the value. As for different sheet the changes have to be made accordingly. This is the reason i was using regex. the solution you posted works prefect but wont wont work sheets with other value.

Comment: I provided you the solution in the answer

Comment: Please mark the answer as right answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Your job design will look like this

[image]

Second , using a tSampleRow you will get the range of lines (in your case you would like first line )

[image]

Third , stock your wanted line in a global variable like this

[image]

Finally , in the tmap just get your global variable as such

[image]

Here is the output (I have 201 lignes i will have 201 UK printed ):

```
.--------.
 |tLogRow_1|
 |=------=|
 |mystring|
 |=------=|
 |UK|
 |UK   |
 |UK   |
 |UK   |
 |UK   |

 '--------'

 [statistics] disconnected
```

Job operation ended at 14:00 21/02/2022. [exit code  = 0]